# iOS Core data issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have made a many-to-many relationship. At first I insert all the data in table 1, the rest of the data isn't available right away.

When the data is available I like to connect it to the right table 1 entries. Should I query table 1 and then set the NSSet with the returned data? Or how would one do this?

To elaborate my question here the example:

[ActivityTable] <<--->> [BannerTable]

At viewDidLoad all the activity are upserted in the ActivityTable. Then the banners from the first activity (first upcoming date) is found from the server.

I got the two (it is always two) banners available but how do I set this?

---

Used this with help of the answer:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Banner" inManagedObjectContext:context];
Banner *banner = [[Banner alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
banner.image = shieldDictionary[BANNER_IMAGE];
```

Comment: It's rather unhelpful to think about Core Data in terms of (presumably the RDBMS concept of) tables.

Comment: @JohnCromartie Figured that out now and it helps to understand the concept of core data to NOT think about Rational Database, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the generated NSManagedObject subclasses for your entities...

In your CoreData model each relationship has a name.
Your generated entity classes already contain methods to add/remove relationships you defined in the model. So all you have to do is use one of those methods.

Example:
If the tables are called 'ActivityTable' and 'BannerTable', and the relationship in 'ActivityTable' is called 'banners', then the generated methods look like:

```
- addBannersObject:(BannerTable *)value;
- removeBannersObject:(BannerTable *)value;
- addBanners:(NSSet *)value;
- removeBanners:(NSSet *)value;
```

Comment: Yes, you can use the returned objects directly.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data manages a graph of objects, not tables.

The easiest way to realize many-to-many relationships is to use the dynamically-generated accessors like `add<Key>Object:` and `remove<Key>s:`.

For instance:

```
[anActivity addBannerObject:aBanner];
```

You can use the data model editor to generate class files for your models which declare these generated methods. You can also use `-mutableSetValueForKey:` to get a proxy that lets you add and remove objects from a relationship. i.e.:

```
NSMutableSet *banners = [anActivity mutableSetValueForKey:@"banners"];
[banners addObject:aBanner];
```

It is obviously less verbose to use the generated methods for each relationship, but it achieves the same thing.